# Install Click build targets in Terminal

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, click-packages

The recommended/normal procedure is to install click build targets in Ubuntu SDK but I wanted to know if it's possible to install them in terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK the recommended way is to use `pkcon`. Copy your .click file to the device and run the following command on the device itself (by using `adb shell` or SSH):

```
pkcon --allow-untrusted install-local com.ubuntu.developer.abc.def_0.123_armhf.click
```

This does not require root privileges.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [click](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/click.1.html) command to install packages on your device.

First copy the `.click` file on your device.

Then use the following commands (e.g after creating a remote session with `phablet-shell`):

```
sudo click install --all-users ./com.ubuntu.foo_1.0.click  --allow-unauthenticated
click register com.ubuntu.foo 1.0
```

Just change the name of the package for your needs.

Comment: Thanks but my  question was when you are developing applications for Ubuntu touch you need to install "click build target" (armhf for example). we can install them in Ubuntu SDK but how about installing them by using command line ?